# How does statement, 'for update' works?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am sorry in advance if I sound noob. I am looking through code for stored procedure and I came across:

```
select 
  ...
into 
  ....
from
  ....
where
  ....
for update;
```

I don't understand what is the purpose of `for update;`.
I do understand normal update, similar to: http://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-stored-procedure-update-example/. But not able to get my head around `for update;` and its purpose.

I looked around but could not find clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [document](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/for_update.php):

> The SELECT FOR UPDATE statement allows you to lock the records in the
>   cursor result set. You are not required to make changes to the records
>   in order to use this statement. The record locks are released when the
>   next commit or rollback statement is issued.

Also refer the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) which says:

> The FOR UPDATE clause lets you lock the selected rows so that other
>   users cannot lock or update the rows until you end your transaction.
>   You can specify this clause only in a top-level SELECT statement, not
>   in subqueries.

So the purpose is quite clear it is used when you want to lock your rows during a transaction so that it cannot be used by some other transaction.

You can also refer: [FOR UPDATE Clause in a SELECT Statement](http://oraclexpert.com/for-update-clause-in-a-select-statement/) to get an idea as to how we can use it.

Comment: It is clear now. Thank you. I was not able to find those references for `for update`. Probably, I was googling wrong.

Comment: @DarcliGht:- You are welcome! On a side note: Always try to find the documentation from the original Oracle docs it will always help you in right direction. :)

Comment: Looks like their examples are broken images in that link. Care to paraphrase the pertinent reference?

Comment: I'm also curious how this differs from operations in other rdbms's where I'd expect locking on queries with multi table joins to ensure consistency. What makes Oracle's FOR UPDATE distinctly special from the competition?

Comment: Oracle is an optimist.  Just because there is a multi-table join does not mean those tables should necessarily be locked.  In fact, that can cause huge concurrency problems, particularly in large databases.  In Oracle, without "for update" queries are completely non-blocking.  The same is true of MySQL / InnoDB and many others.